# Problem with compiling scss, compiler doesn't see mixin

Tags: html, css, sass

can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong. I want to have my media queries in **@mixins** but compiler throws an error.
_mixin.scss

```
@mixin media-sm {
@media screen and (max-width:500px) {
    @content
}
```

}

main.scss

```
@import 'kalendarz';
@import 'mixins';
```

_kalendarz.scss

```
@include media-sm{
 .name {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 400;
        margin: 20px;
    }
}
```

error

```
Error: no mixin named media-sm
        on line 102 of sass/c:\Users\Bartek\Documents\programowanie\Website-managing-driving-lessons\_kalendarz.scss
        from line 3 of sass/c:\Users\Bartek\Documents\programowanie\Website-managing-driving-lessons\main.scss
>> @include media-sm {
```

Comment: Is your file called _mixin.scss or _mixins.scss you refer to both names in your question. If the import works for another sass file then put the mixin in there to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some minor improvements to your code like the `;` that was missing after `@content` in `_mixins.scss`. However the main issue was, that you were using `media-sm` in `_kalendarz.scss` while it was only imported to `main.scss`. You can only `@include` a mixin in the same file you `@import` it.

```
// _mixins.scss

@mixin media-sm {
  @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    @content;
  }
}
```

```
// _kalendarz.scss

@import "mixins"; // or preferably `@use "mixins";`, if Version: Dart Sass > 1.23.0

@include media-sm {
  .name {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 20px;
  }
}
```

```
// main.scss

@import "kalendarz";
```